# Adding two ViewData variable in Razor View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, razorengine

I am new in ASP. 
I want to know can i add two `ViewData` variable in `Razor` View of `ASP.net MVC4` that variable pass from controller?

Comment: Yes i find but i don't.

Comment: you find but you don't..that's your fault buddy.. just kidding..

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code for you

```
public ActionResult Detail(int id)
{

  Model model=Repository.Find(id);
  ViewData["key1"]="some data";
  ViewData["key2"]="some other data";3
  //or using ViewBag (dynamic type)
  ViewBag.key1="some data";
  ViewBag.key2="some other data";

  return View(model);

}
```

In View Page

```
@ViewData["key1"]
```

or

```
@ViewBag.key1
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. But i want to know is to add these two variable in view like 2+1 (ViewData["gpcount"] = ViewData["gpcount"] + 1). So i can increase it in loop.

Comment: @wailynnoo, you need to cast and do. like `((int)ViewData["gpcount"])+(int)ViewData["two"])`

Comment: @wailynnoo, you can upvote /mark as right answer if it useful and working for you

Comment: what about this ... ViewData.gpcount += 1; i think this 'll work... as.